# pivot table with duplicate entries without aggregating/grouping using scala and spark-sql

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have a situation similar to that mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239494/duplicate-entries-and-rename-column-row-in-pandas-pivot-table-without-aggregation) question.

But my complete project is in Scala and I'd prefer to exploit scala / spark-sql APIs for time and package-building-and-deployment constraints.

Do we have a method similar to `pandas.DataFrame.unstack` in Scala? Or
is there some other way to achieve this, say some UDFs?