# How to write an efficient multiple criteria search function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, vectorization, vlookup

I have a dataframe like this.

[image]

I want to search in the columns `zip` and `div` and get `type` and apply that result to all unique zips. Kind of pivot function but return the actual value instead of an aggregate function.(Assume there is only one combination of `zip` and `div`)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(list(range(100,200)), ['A','B','C','D','E'])), columns=['zip', 'div'])
df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[np.random.randint(0,499,size=100)]).reset_index()
df1['type'] = np.random.choice(['P','Q','R'],size=df1.shape[0])
```

I have tried apply/lambda function but it is very slow. My data contains 500K rows in df1 with 41K unique `zip`s and 15 unique `div`s

Is there an efficient way to get a result like the following.

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'zip':[100,101],'A':['Q','P'],'B':['Q','Q'],'C':['Q','P'],'D':['Q','R'],'E':['Q','P']})
```

Assume zip is non-numeric.

Comment: You want to [Pivot without aggregating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239494/duplicate-entries-and-rename-column-row-in-pandas-pivot-table-without-aggregatio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate solution, if you would like to use a pivot table:

```
df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index='zip',columns=['div'],aggfunc='first')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
m=df.groupby('zip')['type'].apply(list)
n=pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist(),columns=df['div'].unique(),index=m.index)
print(n)
```

---

```
     A  B  C  D  E
zip               
100  Q  Q  Q  Q  Q
101  P  Q  P  R  P
```

**P.S** *You shouldn't have `div` as a column as this is a pandas function(i suggest you change it to something else apart from div)*

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error on real data. `13 columns passed, passed data had 187 columns` while calculating n